# How to create a list of sublists where the sublists are split strings?

Tags: python

I have to write a program where it reads from the file and prints a list that contains lists of name, lastname. So far I've been able to make it do everything except for the correct form of printing out the information:

```
def main():
file = open("users.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
data2 = data.split("\n")
for line in data2[0:]:
    a = line.split("|")
    print(a)
main()
```

And instead of it printing out [['name1', 'last1'], ['name2', 'last2'], ['name3', 'last3']] like I need, it prints out:

```
['name1', 'last1']
['name2', 'last2']
['name3', 'last3']
```

In the users.txt file, the infromation is :

```
name1|last1
name2|last2
name3|last3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `split` statement will make a single list, which is why you're getting lines like this:

```
['name1', 'last1']
```

If you'd like to store or print a list of lists, you could do the following:

```
names = list()
for line in data2[0:]:
    a = line.split("|")
    names.append(a)
print(names)
```

Better still, we can use `with` to make reading from the file much clearer:

```
def main():
    names = list()
    with open("users.txt", "r") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            names.append(line.split('|'))
    print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_obj = open('names.txt')
names = []
for name in file_obj.readlines():
    names.append(name.replace('\n','').split('|'))

print str(names)
```

if this is `[['name1', 'last1'], ['name2', 'last2'], ['name3', 'last3']]` how you want it just print the string representation of the list

Comment: I don't see how you're getting from the print statement to a representation of a list of lists, as you're not creating a list of lists, as the other answers are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to do this:

```
def main():
    f = open("users.txt", "r")
    data = f.read()
    lst =  [line.split('|') for line in data.split()]
    print lst

main()
```

Comment: Don't use `list` for a variable name, it masks the underlying Python data type and is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main():
    file = open("users.txt", "r")
    data = file.read()
    data2 = data.splitlines()
    data3 = [line.split("|") for line in data2]
    print data3

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the lines of the file, and printing on *each* line, so what ends up being printed are of course... each lines (and not *all* lines as you seem to expect).

To do that, you need to gather your lines first, which you can do by populating a list:

```
lines = []
with open('user.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
for line in data.split('\n'):
    lines.append(line.split('|'))
```

Or more concisely, with a comprehension:

```
with open('user.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.split('|') for line in f]
```

Printing the resulting `lines` list will have the format you expected, i.e. a list of lines, each line being a list of fields.